# Prevent primefaces datatable to jump on first page after rendering

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Is there a way to prevent the primefaces datatable to jump back on the first page after adding or removing an item?

Example:
I have a datatable with a lazy datamodel and pagination.
At the moment I have two pages. Now I add one item and after rendering the paginator jumps to the first page.

Is it possible that this not happen?

```
    <p:dataTable id="persAnwTbl" 
    var="_anweisung"
    value="#{handler.dataModel}"
    style="width:100%"
    widgetVar="persAnwTblVar"
    emptyMessage="#{messages.noData}"
    lazy="true"
    paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
    paginator="true"
    paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
    currentPageReportTemplate="{totalRecords} #{labels.datensaetze} - #{labels.seite} {currentPage} / {totalPages}"
    rows="#{handler.rows}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,30,50,100,200,500,1000"
    binding="#{handler.dataTable}"
    sortBy="#{_anweisung.module.displayName}"
    filteredValue="#{handler.filteredValues}">
...
...
...
/>
```

Edit: 
2019-05-13 --- 03:05pm

```
<p:dataTable id="persAnwTbl" var="_anweisung"
                             value="#{handler.dataModel}"
                             style="width:100%"
                             widgetVar="persAnwTblVar"
                             emptyMessage="#{messages.noData}"
                             lazy="true"
                             paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
                             paginator="true"
                             paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                             currentPageReportTemplate="{totalRecords} #{labels.datensaetze} - #{labels.seite} {currentPage} / {totalPages}"
                             rows="#{handler.rows}"
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,30,50,100,200,500,1000"
                             binding="#{handler.dataTable}"
                             sortBy="#{_anweisung.module.displayName}"
                             filteredValue="#{handler.filteredValues}"
                             first="#{handler.first}">

...
...
...
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just bind the offset of the first displayed row (i.e., the start of the current page) to a field of your model:

```
<p:dataTable
 <!-- ... -->
 first="#{handler.first}"
 <!-- ... -->
>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Just added it, but won't do it. Is there something or to do than just adding this attribute and binding it to a variable in the backing bean? BTW: The bean is @ViewAccessScoped

Comment: @LStrike: it should work... see similar Q/A in Stackoverflow

Comment: @LStrike: Sorry, I haven't worked with `@ViewAccessScoped` so far. Can you e.g.  confirm that the setter for the "first" attribute of your model will be called on page change or that the getter will be called on load?

Comment: The setter is called on the first load and the value of "first" is null. But on change the getter is not called.

Comment: It should be the other way around actually - on the first load, the getter should be called to check which row to display and on page change the setter should be called to persist the current "first" row in the model. Furthermore, as you support lazy loading, you could try to set the "first" field of your model when handling the "lazy" callback.

Comment: @Smutje: Yes you are right. But still every time I add or remove an item, after rendering the view jumps back to the first page....

Comment: So, it is confirmable that a) the correct "first" value is being written to the model, that b) the correct "first" value then gets read from the model but that c) the table still displays the first page?

Comment: That is correct. I may have found the problem. There is a method in the bean, which recreates the datamodel if I remove an item.

Answer (score 0):

Smutje's answer is right, but not suffice for my code to work.(I am using PF 6.0.19 btw).

Fews steps are required for making the whole thing work

1. Add `first` attribute to your `p:datatable` (Smutje's answer)
2. You have to call `DataTable.setFirst()` as well in your bean listener method.

   E.g.

   ```
   public void addItem(){
       //Your add item code
       //Assume your `first` getter method can be called by handler.getFirst()
       ((DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance.getViewRoot().findComponent("YOUR_DATATABLE_ID")).setFirst(handler.getFirst());
   }
   ```

Comment: This is only needed if you don't update the full datatable. Otherwise I'd expect this to be superfluous.